# struct initialize to satisfy an interface without explicit method definition

Tags: struct, interface, go

Given pseudo go code below:

```
type(
    MyStruct struct {
        AFunction  func(string) ([]byte, error)
    }

    MyInterface interface {
        AFunction(string) ([]byte, error)
    }
)

func NeedThis(s string) ([]byte, error){
    //relevant function stuff
}

m := &MyStruct{AFunction: NeedThis}
```

The problem arises that m does not satisfy the MyInterface interface; and I can somewhat see why this would be so. Is there a way to attach functions to a struct in such a way that the constructed struct satisfies an interface without actually building out defining methods on the struct? I'm having some shadowy/faulty reasoning around this, maybe help to clarify this for me or show a better way to reason through this situation.

Comment: Can you better explain the problem you're trying to solve? You see that this isn't directly possible, so I'm not sure where to go with an answer.

Comment: I'm working on a some things, using one thing to extend another of the same which may or may not provide assets, you can see how it ended up here: https://github.com/thrisp/fleet/blob/develop/asset.go and here https://github.com/thrisp/fleet_skeleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just define a method `AFunction` on `MyStruct` that dispatches to the stored `AFunction` function pointer? It's not ideal if you have a lot of these, but I think it does the job?

i.e. something like

```
func (s MyStruct) AFunction(str string) ([]byte, error) {
    return s.AFunction(str)
}
```

edit: the above may cause the compiler to error because `s.AFunction` is ambiguous, so you might have to give them (the method and the function pointer) different names, but it should give the right idea.

Comment: Yes, this is somewhat what I needed to do

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in another struct that implements the interface:

http://play.golang.org/p/AgnYAWBdUp

```
package main

import "fmt"

type (
    MyStruct struct {
        AFunction func(string) ([]byte, error)
    }

    MyInterface interface {
        AFunction(string) ([]byte, error)
    }
)

func NeedThis(s string) ([]byte, error) {
    //relevant function stuff
    return nil, nil
}

type Proxy struct {
    *MyStruct
}

func (x *Proxy) AFunction(s string) ([]byte, error) {
    return x.MyStruct.AFunction(s)
}

func main() {

    m := &MyStruct{AFunction: NeedThis}
    p := &Proxy{m}
    _, ok := MyInterface(p).(MyInterface)
    fmt.Println(ok)
}
```